# apt-get update really slow when i'm at the university

Tags: apt, repository, aptitude

When i'm using my university connection I can't run `apt-get update` normally as I do at home or any other place.

Everything else (that use connection) works properly.

I've already tried to change the repositories provider to a local one (Brasil) and now i'm using the official Canonical repos.

It doesn't leave 0% [waiting headers] part.

How could I debug this? What should I tracert to find where the connection is goin down?

Comment: See if you can just browse the repo sites with a web browser.  They may be black-holing or throttling those servers in particular.  If they use Ubuntu at the university, they may drop traffic to known repositories so they can sort of enforce what's available in the local college repository.

Comment: @aking1012 - Yeah, I can browse the repositories on `archive.ubuntu.com` via my browser... they don't use Ubuntu here, but AFAIK they didn't blocked the connection... at least not intentionally

Comment: Another possibility is that they dynamically shape traffic per website/url.  This would make any multimedia sites and distribution update sites painfully slow(the more it uses the less it gets type of thing).  You could try proxies, but that's complicated.  <-- less likely, but there's a lab at a local community college where they teach an OS course and Windows update get's throttled by the barracuda system they have installed.

Comment: You can take a look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/135818/the-size-of-apt-get-update-lists-is-too-big/ but I'm not sure that problem results in a stall at 0% [waiting headers]. It is a current anomaly with apt-get update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reinstalled the operating system and everything worked good... sadly i didn't figured out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If your university is slowing down traffic between your computer and specific Internet servers (one way of doing what has been suggested in the comments), then you could probably solve your problem by switching to a different download mirror.

The easiest way to change this is in the Software Sources window. I don't know what release/flavor of Ubuntu you're running so it's hard to provide optimal instructions for bringing that up graphically, but you can probably bring it up by running `gksu software-properties-gtk`.

Answer (score 0):

Many universities run their own Ubuntu mirrors. You should ask around and see if there is a local mirror.