# Package updates always download too much data

Tags: apt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [the size of apt-get update lists is too big](https://askubuntu.com/questions/135818/the-size-of-apt-get-update-lists-is-too-big)

When I update Ubuntu (either with `apt-get update` or using the GUI-based check for updates), it downloads a large amount of data, 19.xx MB every time, and often takes an unusually long time to to check.

This behavior didn't exist in 11.10, or in 11.04 (or in Mint) -- in earlier versions, it seemed to check intelligently for updates, and only download what was necessary.  The initial update would download the whole 19MB or so, but subsequent updates were only about 2 to 3 MB.   If no packages were updated, nothing would be downloaded.

But since upgrading to 12.04, every time I update, it downloads 19MB (meaning that it seems to start from scratch every time)....

Is there a database or cache problem, or something else that I can check to correct this?

Comment: if you wish to put a  bounty - please do so on the dupe question - link in your question.  Explain carefully in the bounty explanation what alternative answer your are seeking that the current answers do not offer.  Thanks.