# the size of apt get update list is too big everytime?

Tags: 12.04, apt, updates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [the size of apt-get update lists is too big](https://askubuntu.com/questions/135818/the-size-of-apt-get-update-lists-is-too-big)

In Ubuntu 12.04, the following packages are fetched every time I run `sudo apt-get update`.
Dear ubuntu Experts please tell me how to stop this.

```
ranjeet@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get update
Ign http://dl.google.com stable InRelease
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise InRelease                      
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise InRelease                      
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise InRelease                       
Get:1 http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg [198 B]                
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security InRelease                      
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise InRelease                      
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates InRelease              
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise InRelease                       
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise InRelease                       
Get:2 http://dl.google.com stable Release [1,347 B]                            
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release.gpg                               
Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security Release.gpg [198 B]          
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg [198 B]                    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release.gpg                               
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release.gpg                               
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release.gpg                               
Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security Release [49.6 kB]            
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release.gpg [198 B]            
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release.gpg                               
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise Release [49.6 kB]                      
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release                                   
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release                                   
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release                                   
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release                                   
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release                                   
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main TranslationIndex                     
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main TranslationIndex                     
Get:8 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted Sources [14 B]    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Sources                              
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release [49.6 kB]              
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main amd64 Packages                       
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main i386 Packages                        
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main TranslationIndex                     
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Sources                              
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main amd64 Packages                       
Get:10 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe Sources [4,522 B]  
Get:11 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse Sources [696 B]  
Get:12 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main Sources [12.6 kB]      
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main i386 Packages                        
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main TranslationIndex                     
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Sources                              
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main amd64 Packages                       
Get:13 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted amd64 Packages [14 B]
Get:14 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe amd64 Packages [10.3 kB]
Get:15 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse amd64 Packages [1,142 B]
Get:16 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main amd64 Packages [42.8 kB]
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main i386 Packages                        
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main TranslationIndex                     
Get:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Sources [5,470 B]          
Get:18 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Sources [5,019 kB]           
Get:19 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted i386 Packages [14 B]
Get:20 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe i386 Packages [10.3 kB]
Get:21 http://dl.google.com stable/main amd64 Packages [1,238 B]               
Get:22 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse i386 Packages [1,393 B]
Get:23 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main i386 Packages [43.9 kB]
Get:24 http://dl.google.com stable/main i386 Packages [1,248 B]                
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main TranslationIndex                          
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Sources                              
  404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main amd64 Packages                       
  404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main i386 Packages                        
  404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Sources                              
  404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main amd64 Packages                       
  404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main i386 Packages                        
  404  Not Found
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en_US                    
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en                       
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en_US                    
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en_US                         
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en                            
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en                                                                                       
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en_US                                                                                    
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en                                                                                       
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en_US                                                                                    
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en                                                                                       
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en_US                                                                                    
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en                                                                                       
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main TranslationIndex                                                                          
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse TranslationIndex                                                                    
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted TranslationIndex                                                                    
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe TranslationIndex                                                                      
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main Translation-en                                                                            
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse Translation-en                                                                      
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted Translation-en                                                                      
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe Translation-en                                                                        
Get:25 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Sources [155 kB]                                                                           
Get:26 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Sources [934 kB]                                                                                 
Get:27 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted amd64 Packages [8,452 B]                                                                   
Get:28 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe amd64 Packages [4,786 kB]                                                                    
Get:29 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse amd64 Packages [119 kB]                                                                    
Get:30 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/main amd64 Packages [1,273 kB]                                                                        
Get:31 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted i386 Packages [8,431 B]                                                                    
Get:32 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe i386 Packages [4,796 kB]                                                                     
Get:33 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse i386 Packages [121 kB]                                                                     
Get:34 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/main i386 Packages [1,274 kB]                                                                         
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/main TranslationIndex                                                                                    
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse TranslationIndex                                                                              
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted TranslationIndex                                                                              
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe TranslationIndex                                                                                
Get:35 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted Sources [1,379 B]                                                                  
Get:36 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Sources [14.7 kB]                                                                    
Get:37 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse Sources [696 B]                                                                    
Get:38 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Sources [47.9 kB]                                                                        
Get:39 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [2,417 B]                                                           
Get:40 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe amd64 Packages [37.1 kB]                                                             
Get:41 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [1,142 B]                                                           
Get:42 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main amd64 Packages [120 kB]                                                                  
Get:43 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted i386 Packages [2,439 B]                                                            
Get:44 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe i386 Packages [37.6 kB]                                                              
Get:45 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse i386 Packages [1,393 B]                                                            
Get:46 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main i386 Packages [121 kB]                                                                   
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main TranslationIndex                                                                            
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse TranslationIndex                                                                      
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted TranslationIndex                                                                      
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe TranslationIndex                                                                        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en                                                                                      
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Translation-en                                                                                
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Translation-en                                                                                
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Translation-en                                                                                  
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Translation-en                                                                              
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse Translation-en                                                                        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted Translation-en                                                                        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Translation-en                                                                          
Fetched 19.2 MB in 8min 59s (35.5 kB/s)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you understand what main and universe are. They are not packages, but lists of available packages.

Running `sudo apt-get update` downloads these lists of packages, but you have to run `sudo apt-get upgrade` in order to actually install the available updates.

Therefore it is vitally important to always update your main and universe package lists. However the downloads should not be 13MB - your question is effectively a duplicate of this one: [the size of apt-get update lists is too big](https://askubuntu.com/questions/135818/the-size-of-apt-get-update-lists-is-too-big)
.

Comment: I am new to ubuntu just 2 days back i installed ubuntu on my Acer Aspire 4736, that is why i dont have deep knowledge about ubuntu.

Answer (score -1):

#### *edit: Question is edited so answering this*

create shell script as,

```
gksudo gedit /usr/bin/update-apt
```

paste below script in gedit, get file name `XXXX` and `XXX` from `/var/lib/apt/lists/` as commented in script ( those files will be having larger size in my case for natty 9 and 28 MB).

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo touch /var/lib/apt/lists/XXXX # XXXX means full name of file ending with '_main_binary-i386_Packages'
sudo touch /var/lib/apt/lists/XXX # XXX means full name of file ending with '_universe_binary-i386_Packages'
sudo apt-get update
```

give execution permission

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/update-apt
```

now whenever you want to `sudo apt-get update` try `update-apt`.

you've done it.

---

---

*this answer was given for first unedited question*

[image]

Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and run `software-properties-gtk`. or open `Software Sources`

Just uncheck

```
 Canonical-supported Open Source software (main)
 Community-maintained open Source software (universe)
```

then hit `close` then hit `reload`

thats it.

Comment: keep in mind that you won't get notified for latest updates.

Comment: to **Gentle downvoter**, can you please tell me what is wrong with this answer? I hope I will have a reason.